# 'No WiFi adapter found' in Ubuntu 20.04/ Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, wireless, 22.04, asus, iwlwifi

I am unable to connect to the WiFi. My laptop is a dual boot with Windows 11 and Ubuntu 20.04. The WiFi is able to connect with the Windows 11, but not with the Ubuntu.

As per ChanganAuto's request, the results of running `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` are:

```
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0264]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

I also attached an image here.

[image]

As per Chili555's request, the results of running `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` are:

```
[    9.972250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   10.202615] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[   10.202625] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[   10.202835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   13.084510] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9461, REV=0x354
[   13.234057] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: base HW address: 70:a6:cc:73:19:05
[   14.675800] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3 wlo1: renamed from wlan1
```

Here is the full wireless diagnostic log generated after running Wireless Info Script: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/5rX9spgnJX/

---

Hey Chili555, I tried as per your directions. Firstly disabled fast boot (from BIOS as well as the Windows 11[Fast Startup], As I was unable to figure it out which one). Then later on I attached Ethernet and ran `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y iw` and detached the Ethernet and rebooted. And when I ran this `nmcli device wifi list` command, it was all blank
[image]

And also would like to provide you this additional information after running the command `lshw -C network`. It shows DISABLED for Wireless Network
[image]

---

Here is the `rfkill list all`:

[image]

And here is the `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command. Also when dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must. Make sure it's disabled and shutdown Windows, don't reboot directly to Ubuntu.

Comment: Would be good to know if we'd know your hardware (as ChanganAuto suggests). Usually you'd need a newer kernel

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: It looks perfectly normal so far. Are you able to see your network when you click the Network Manager icon? Does it try to connect and fail? What exactly, do you mean "unable to connect to the WiFi"?

Comment: @chili555:  I am not able to see any of the WiFi Connections, not even saved ones. When I open the 'Settings > Network' it nowhere shows the 'WiFi' icon. And when I open 'WiFi Settings' directly by searching WiFi keyword, it shows 'No Wi-Fi Adapter Found'

Comment: Please provide a full wireless diagnostic: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180 We need *much* more information in order to proceed.

Comment: Please confirm that Fast Boot is turned off in Windows: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled With the ethernet attached, do: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y iw` Detach the ethernet, reboot and show us: `nmcli device wifi list`

Comment: Disabled? Please show us: `rfkill list all` and: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: i experienced the same problem i solved it by reinstalling Ubuntu

Comment: I have already reinstalled it twice. It works all good in the beginning, but after a day or 2 days. it gets disabled. Hence I want to know the root cause. I cannot keep reinstalling it every time I face this issue.

Comment: Hello @chili555, I would also like to update one more thing as I doubt it might be one of the reason. I have installed 'Gnome Extensions' and 'Gnome Tweaks' does this affect wireless drivers?

Comment: try any other LTS versions of linux  may be because of broken bootable medium. make sure your wifi hardware working properly.

Comment: Did that too. Firstly I reinstalled with the same version i.e. with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. And the second time I installed with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Still facing the same issue. And about hardware working properly, As the laptop is in dual boot, the wifi works very well in Windows 11. Hence I don't think it is any hardware problem

Comment: @chili555      Can you please reply, as I was expecting answer from you. Please do help me in resolving the issue, as it is crucial.

Comment: Please detach the ethernet. Next, run: `sudo ip link set wlo1 up` Any errors or messages? Next, try: `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan` Any scan results? No need to post them, just tell us if there are or are not results and any errors or messages. This is my least favorite type of problem. Everything looks perfect except it just doesn't work.

Comment: @chili555       I did as you said, disconnected the Ethernet and run the ```sudo ip link set wlo1 up``` didn't throw any messages nor any errors. Next I tried the ```sudo iwlist wlo1scan``` and guess what it scanned all the available WiFi Hotspots. Please let me know what to do next, and Hats off to you and your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalling the NetworkManager resolved the issue. i.e. by `sudo apt-get reinstall network-manager`.

Why I tried reinstalling:
Firstly I tried `nmcli` which showed that the SW `Plugin is missing` for the wireless.  This helped me to narrow down things to check with the network manager.

For all those who commented, thanks for your precious time and helping me out in finding a solution. Special thanks to Chili555